Defining a norm that maximizes $x+x^2$
I'm working through some functional analysis exercises, and I've come across a problem that has stumped me. The setup considers three elements of $C^\infty[-1,1]$ defined by
$$\begin{align}f_1(x)&=x,\\f_2(x)&=x+x^2,\text{ and}\\f_3(x)&=x+x^2+x^3.\end{align}$$
The objective is to find three different norms for the space that satisfy (individually, of course) these properties:
$$\begin{align}||f_1(x)||_A&>||f_2(x)||_A \text{ and }||f_1(x)||_A>||f_3(x)||_A,\tag{A}\\||f_2(x)||_B&>||f_1(x)||_B \text{ and }||f_2(x)||_B>||f_3(x)||_B,\text{ and}\tag{B}\\||f_3(x)||_C&>||f_1(x)||_C \text{ and }||f_3(x)||_C>||f_1(x)||_C.\tag{C}\end{align}$$
For objective $(A)$, I found that the following norm is satisfactory:
$$||f||_A=\left[\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{-1}^x f(t)\text{ dt}\right)^2\text{dx}\right]^\frac12.$$
Likewise for objective $(C)$, I found the 1-norm is satisfactory:
$$||f||_C=\int_{-1}^1|f(x)|\text{ dx}.$$
However, I can't seem to find any norm that satisfies objective $(B)$, making $f_2(x)$ the largest. I even experimented with weighted norms, e.g.:
$$||f||_W=\left[\int_{-1}^1w(x)f(x)^2\text{ dx}\right]^\frac12,$$
where $w(x)>0$, trying a number of weighting functions $w(x)$, but nothing I tried made $f_2(x)$ the largest. Any advice on how to proceed? Also, is there any intuition for how to pick a suitable norm in general?

For real constants $a,b,c$ let
$$\|f\|=|af'(0)+bf''(0)+cf'''(0)|+\|f\|_\infty$$
Then $$\|f_1\|=|a|+1 .\ \|f_2\|=|a+2b|+2,\ \|f_3\|=|a+2b+3c|+3$$ By playing around with the constants we can achieve any of the three conditions. For example fix $b,$ and let $a=0,$ $2b+3c=0.$ Then $\|f_1\|=1,\ \|f_3\|=3$ and $\|f_2\|=2|b|+2. $
Hence $b=1$ gives  (B).
Similarly $c=0,\ a+2b=0$ and $a= 3$  give (A), while
$a=b=c=0 $ give (C).
For any linear space and linearly independent elements $v_1,v_2,v_3$ it is possible to achieve all three conditions with suitable three norms.
